# Spark: reading tables and filtering by partition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to understand Spark's evaluation.

There is a table table_name which is partitioned by partition_column. It's an external table stored in a parquet format.
Now, consider the following line

```
val df = spark.read.table(table_name).filter(partition_column=partition_value)
```

Due to Spark's lazy evaluation is it going to apply predicate pushdown and only scan the folder where partition_column=partition_value? Or is it about to read the entire table and filter out later?

Comment: just to add details to the answer, you need to include all `partition_column` columns into your `filter` predicate, if you have a few. See `Restrictions on column filters` https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkPredicatePushdown.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **.explain** to see result yourself.

But parquet does get push down applied.

Transformations, filters, mapping, etc. are all fused together. The lazy aspect is indeed true, albeit you did it all on one statement.

So, answer is YES, Spark will generate code to filter at source.

Comment: Good answer is very useful for me too